# Last leg canceled, airline isn't cooperating

Tags: airlines, cancellations, spirit-airlines

My son is traveling from Peru to Atlanta, changing at Fort Lauderdale, on Spirit Airlines. He has reached FLL but Spirit canceled his FLL to ATL flight. (No apparent reason, not weather related as far as I can see.) They are telling him they can't book him to ATL for another two days. They're offering "compensation" but it won't cover rebooking.

What are applicable laws?

Comment: Are you sure you have the full story and there’s no misunderstanding? There was one cancelled flight but there are plenty more, and there are availabilities... Something’s not quite right here...

Comment: Where are you seeing the availabilities? They insisted there were none for two days, and all the Spirit flights from FLL to ATL on that day showed as "Sold Out".

Comment: Did a quick Google Flights search from my phone, didn't really look into too much detail but it was still showing one flight for Sunday and several for Monday. Right now on the Spirit site it's showing availabilities for the 6am, 6:09pm and 10:58pm flights on Monday (though there's only 1 seat left for the first two, I don't know how many people are in your son's party?).

Comment: There were many Spirit flights but all were shown as fully booked when I looked. There were three people in the party, but that wasn't really the point -- staying overnight was really not an option because he had commitments for the next day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > What are applicable laws?

The rules are spelled out in Spirit's Contract of Carriage (https://www.spirit.com/Content/Documents/en-US/Contract_of_Carriage.pdf) and terms and condition (https://www.spirit.com/Legal.aspx), which you agreed to at time of booking.

The contract of carriage says in section 8.2

> Rebooking When a guest holding a confirmed reservation on a Spirit
>   flight which is delayed because of a schedule irregularity (including
>   but not limited to, a missed connection, flight cancellation, omission
>   of a scheduled stop, substitution of equipment, or schedule change),
>   Spirit may rebook the guest on Spirit's first flight on which seats
>   are available to the guest's original destination without additional
>   charge. Our staff will focus on rebooking as many guests as possible
>   on alternate flights, either direct to the destination or via
>   connections through other airports to best accommodate the guest’s
>   needs. A change may be made to an itinerary without a charge and/or
>   fare difference when the itinerary was affected by a cancelled flight,
>   an eligible schedule change or a delayed flight (greater than two
>   hours from the original departure time) provided:
>
> - The same departure and arrival airports are booked and;
> - The itinerary is rebooked within Spirit’s authorized date ranges (currently within 7 days of the departure date).
>
> With limited exceptions, Spirit will not reimburse
>   guests for flights that they book on other carriers.

That's unfortunately open to interpretation, so I think it's probably more important right now to figure out how to get your son to Atlanta most efficiently. Today looks pretty bleak, but tomorrow there are non-stop flights on Spirit and Jet Blue for $200-$250. It's puzzling that Spirit claims "no seats available". Check online booking sites and document any available Sprit flights. If they have open seats, they need to give them to your son. If they don't, they should rebook him on Jet Blue. Now it's time to start a solid paper trail.

Comment: He found a Delta flight from Fort Meyers, 2 hours drive away -- booked that and is Ubering to the other airport. If he leaves soon he should have plenty of time. It will end up costing a couple hundred dollars more than expected, even including the refund Spirit gave him.

Comment: @iayork Two words - "Travel insurance". If he doesn't have it, he should.  If the flight was payed for with a credit card check to see if they have coverage.

Comment: It’s in situations like these that you really don’t understand how people could vote to leave the EU which have rights to passengers, basically replacing “may” with “must” in that quote.

Comment: @Doc Travel insurance is even more of a rook.  You end up spending a couple days fighting with them and end up with nothing but frayed nerves.  In particular, the travel insurance will say "we won't cover it since Spirit is supposed to" or other such thing.

Comment: @Harper That may be your experience.  It is not mine.

Comment: What will "travel insurance" cover? The cost of the flight? That was refunded, and not the concern. The extra cost in getting the Uber and the other flight? We can try with the credit card company, but I'm skeptical.

Comment: @iayork: if you already have travel insurance, you need to carefully read the policy about what is covered.  Most policies have a bewildering set of rules and exclusions. If you don't have any, it's too late anyway

Comment: We have whatever is on the card he bought the flight with (we're trying to figure that out) and my son has a vague idea that he had travel insurance from another source ... I'm not optimistic, but we're looking into it and I appreciate the suggestion here